# Array of Arrays with multiple objects

Tags: c#, arrays

I am really new to C#.  I have multiple computer instances and they each have a name, stop, start and restart commands associated with each one.  I want to read in the information from a file.

So I want to end up with `instancelist[0].Instance_name=Enterprise1` and `instancelist[0].Instance_stop=@Enterprise_stop` and `instancelist[1].Instance_name=Enterprise5` and so on.  I can figure out how to do the declaration.

```
public class Instance
{
    public string Instance_name;
    public string Instance_stop;

    public string Instance_restart;
    public string Instance_backup;
} 

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num_instances=0;

    /** CAN'T figure out the declaration. I'm currently thinking array of array? */

    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C......");

    while(true)
    {
        instancelist[num_instance].Instance_name=file.ReadLine();
        instancelist[num_instance].Instance_stop=file.ReadLine();
        // and so on.......
        num_instance++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you are talking about 'jagged' arrays: here is a link that  explains the usage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Comment: Hi there! I took the time to format your code, but in future you should make your code presentable before posting your question. (To post a lot of code at once, use the 'Code Sample' selection to indent it all by four spaces, which makes it format as code)

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off using a collection instead of an array.  It's easier to work with if the number of elements changes.  In your case, you're reading the strings from a file, so you're unlikely to know the size of the list ahead of time.

You'll also need a DTO class, however.  So here's some code (untested):

```
// DTO Class
public class Instance
{
   public string Instance_Start { get; set; }
   public string Instance_Stop { get; set; }
}

var instanceList = new List<Instance>;
var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(myFile);

while(!file.EndOfStream)
{
    var instance = new Instance
    {
        Instance_Start = file.Readline();
        Instance_Stop = file.Readline();
    };

    instanceList.Add(instance);
    num_instance++;
}
```

Note that you can still access elements on instanceList by index, as in

```
instanceList[0].InstanceStart
```

Comment: You don't actually answer the OP's question properly... the instance list is not a set of strings, it's a set of Instance objects.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get a collection of these `Instance` objects, each of which will be parsed from a set of contiguous lines in a file.

I would recommend something like this:

```
// First: a static method to create an Instance object from a few
// consecutive lines in a stream
class Instance
{
    public static Instance ReadFromStream(StreamReader reader)
    {
        var instance = new Instance();
        instance.InstanceName = reader.ReadLine();
        instance.InstanceStop = reader.ReadLine();
        // etc.
        return instance;
    }
}

// Then, elsewhere: use a List<T> (an expandable collection)
// to store all the instances you create from reading the file.
// Note that the 'using' statement automatically closes the file
// for you when you're done.
var instances = new List<Instance>();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        instances.Add(Instance.ReadFromStream(reader));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is rather vague but here's my attempt at an answer.

Apparantly you have a class named 'Instance', I would suggest creating a list of 'Instance' class instances:

```
using System.Collections.Generic; // Add this to the rest of 'usings' 

public static void Main(string[], args)
{
    // Create a new stream to read the file
    StreamReader SReader = new StreamReader("C:\file.txt");

    // Create a list of 'Instance' class instances
    List<Instance> AllInstances = new List<Instance>();

    // Keep reading until we've reached the end of the stream
    while(SReader.Peek() > 0)
    {
         // Read the line
         string CurrentLine = SReader.ReadLine(); // if you call this multiple times in this loop you proceed multiple lines in the file..

         // Create an new instance of the 'Instance' class
         Instance CurrentInstance = new Instance();

         // Assign the 'Name' property
         CurrentInstance.Name = CurrentLine;

         // Add class instance to the list
         AllInstances.Add(CurrentInstance);
    }

    // Close the stream
    SReader.Close();
}
```

At the end you'll have a list of 'Instance' classes. For more information regarding List:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

And regarding the StreamReader:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are really only appropriate if you know how many you need ahead of time and if you won't be inserting or removing elements.  Even then, a collection object like a List is often preferable.

You could do something like this:

```
// Convention in C# is to use properties instead of fields for something like this
// also, having the class name in the field name is redundant
public class Instance
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Stop {get;set;}

    public string Restart {get;set;}
    public string Backup {get;set;}
} 

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Instance> items = new List<Instance>();

    // the using block will close the file handle
    using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C......"))
    {
        while(true)
        {
            String name = file.ReadLine(), stop = file.ReadLine(), restart = file.ReadLine(), backup = file.ReadLine();
            if (name == null || stop == null || restart == null || backup == null)
                break; // I didn't test it, but this should work for determining the end of the file
            items.Add(new Instance(){
               Name = name,
               Stop = stop,
               Restart = restart,
               Backup = backup
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to be able to find the values for a particular name, there are two approaches.  One is to loop through comparing against the Name property and store the List index.  The more idiomatic way of doing this (though it's not as easy for a new-comer to read) is:

```
String nameToFind = "...";
String stop = items.Where(item => item.Name == nameToFind).FirstOrDefault().Stop;
```

Note that `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` if no such element is found, in which case the `.Stop` dereference will throw an Exception.

On the other hand, if you really want this whole data structure to be indexed by name, a `List` (or an array) may not be the best way to go.  Another solution could be:

```
public class Instance2
{
    public string Stop {get;set;}
    public string Restart {get;set;}
    public string Backup {get;set;}
} 

Dictionary<String, Instance2> items = new Dictionary<String, Instance2>();

// ...

items[name] = new Instance2(){Stop = stop,
    Restart = restart,
    Backup = backup};
```

With a data structure like this, looking up by name is much more efficient (`O(log(n))` compared to `O(n)`).  You would just do:

```
String nameToFind = "...";
String stop = items[nameToFind].Stop;
```

Comment: I like this, but after it is read into the list, I need to be able to search for a "Name" and return the value in "Stop".  If the List is not indexed how would I do a search on the Name and return the string in Stop.  Maybe I just don't understand the List concept?  Because it just seems like a long list of objects without the name, stop, restart and backup being tied together.

Comment: Updated.  Lists are easy to search.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about them being tied together.  The pieces of associated data all live in the same object.  Maybe run it in a debugger and you can see how the List or Dictionary looks.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I was able to get this working!  I had been working on it for literally days.  Now I just have to integrate my small piece into the large program I was handed.

Comment: Glad to help.  If you found it helpful, can you vote this answer up and mark it as the "best answer"?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, if you know the number of instances beforehand you could use an array, but otherwise you may as well use a `List<Instance>`.

```
public static void main(string[] args)
{
    List<Instance> instancelist = new List<Instance>();

    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C......");
    while (! file.EndOfStream ) // rather than while(true) which never stops
    {
          // Even if this were in an array, instancelist[i].Instance_name would be a null pointer exception,
          // So we create the instance and then add it to the list
          var instance = new Instance(); 
          instance.Instance_name = file.ReadLine();
          //... etc

          instancelist.Add(instance);
    }
}
```